# Can't import _PaDeviceInfo from PyAudio

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyaudio, python-typing

Writing a simple application using pyaudio, and trying to learn python's typing hint system.  I can't use the _PaDeviceInfo type. Even though it autocompletes in VSCode, it errors out when I run the code, saying "cannot import name '_PaDeviceInfo' from 'pyaudio'(..lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py)".

I think this alias could be coming from the .pyi file? I'm using VSCode with Pylance and Pyright.  I've installed pyaudio and types-pyaudio in this virtual environment.  Thanks.

```
from pyaudio import PyAudio, Stream, _PaDeviceInfo

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
device_info  : _PaDeviceInfo = p.get_device_info_by_index(device_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pyaudio contains only two classes：PyAdudio and Stream.

```
from pyaudio import PyAudio, Stream, _PaDeviceInfo
```

Delete the last ", _PaDeviceInfo".It doesn't belong here.
Here is the API for pyaudio:https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#pyaudio.PyAudio